# Qt Creator ha dejado de funcionar tras una actualización

Tags: linux, qt, qt-creator

Hoy he actualizado la versión Qt Creator de la versión 4.13.2 a la 4.13.3. Tras lo cual Qt Creator ya no arranca.

Cuanto intento arrancarla desde la consola recibo el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
jlopez > Tools > QtCreator > bin > ./qtcreator
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Abortado
```

He estado buscando en internet cómo solucionarlo pero ninguna de las sugerencias que probado ha funcionado. Entre ellas:

- Reinstalar libxcb-xinerama0 (`sudo apt install libxcb-xinerama0*`)
- Reinstalar completamente Qt y eliminar los directorios que tiene Qt dentro de `~/.config`. Obviamente algo se queda porque el problema sigue existiendo al volver a instalar Qt pero no se qué archivos son ni dónde se encuentran.

Estoy usando Debian 10 con el entorno de escritorio GNOME y la versión de Qt 5.12 comunity.

¿Alguna sugerencia? ¿Alguien sabe cómo solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿como has actualizado QtCreator? ¿Cual es la salida si ejecutas: `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 qtcreator`?

Comment: He actualizado desde el programa Qt Maintenance. Si ejecuto lo que me comentas me sale exactamente el mismo mensaje.

Comment: Probablemente sea un bug, te recomiendo reinstalar la version antigua de QtCreator